# How to integrate FB like button in sencha touch 2.0.0 application

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch application development. Currently I am following sencha touch 2.0.0 .
all I need to know is the step by step way to integrate the FACEBOOK-LIKE button into my sencha touch 2.0.0 application.

any type of answers, code samples, tutorials are appreciated.

Comment: ok....got the way to integrate FACEBOOK-LIKE button with authentication into sencha touch 2.0.0 .

get your desired answer over here :

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198837-how-to-integrate-FB-like-button-in-sencha-touch-2.0.0-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some of the below posts on Sencha Touch forum might help you.

- [Add own facebook like button](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?197727-Add-own-facebook-like-button)
- [FB like Button on Sencha Touch Toolbar](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?123386-FB-Like-button-on-Sencha-Touch-Toolbar)